# How can I customize the syntax highlighting in Visual Studio 2005?

Tags: visual-studio, syntax-highlighting

Is it possible to customize the syntax highlighting in Visual Studio 2005? Up to now, I found no way to do this.

In eclipse for example, it's possible to setup custom highlighting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you mean more than just changing the colors -- like defining a new language with its own symbols and keywords?  If so,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165041(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 3):

Yes, see Tools...Options....Fonts and Colors.

Here is a [theme gallery](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/VisualStudioProgrammerThemesGallery.aspx) if you want to browse some options.

Comment: I cannot find the entry "Fonts and Colors" ... I use a german version of visual studio 2005, may be the menu entries are located differently?

Answer (score 1):

For C++, you can add a file called usertype.dat that contains your list of custom keywords.

This [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy61y8b8(VS.80).aspx) has a few more details.

Answer (score 0):

This is an great free library: http://studiostyl.es/

Import the settings Via Tools->Import/Export Settings