# Is there a Perl extension for Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, perl

Does anyone know if there is an extension or plugin for Visual Studio (any version) that will recognize Perl syntax highlighting? I want to edit the Perl files in my vs projects, but it gets hard to read sometimes.

Comment: @Ether - Eclipse brings any PC without gazillion jigabytes of RAM to its knees. vim is totally un-usable to people from non-vi background from what I experienced. Komodo IDE is not free, I think. Padre is probably less polished (just a dumb assumption based on the fact that AFAIK it's still in development - I never used it so it's a fact-less guess and I apologize in advance if it is not the case - I do feel nothing but respect for Padre's author). Plus, NONE OF THEM can be used to work on VS projects :)

Comment: @DVK: Visual Studio, EPIC, Komodo, VIM, and even EMACS are also "in development". ;)  But for the most part, yeah.

Comment: @DVK Padre is a very good editor for Perl. vim is the only reason I'm not using it right now.

Comment: @molecules - the question is, is VS an inferior IDE for the languages it works with (e.g. C#/C++) compared to Padre for Perl, as Ether seems to imply? I doubt.

Comment: @DVK - I used to program in C# all the time, and VS was wonderful for that.

Comment: A long time ago, I used ActiveState Visual Perl, which was exactly what you're looking for... I wonder if it's still available anywhere.

Comment: Alas, Visual Perl was discontinued in 2005

Comment: Anyone who was directed here, I'll give you just a fair warning; since this post is a teenager now, I'd look elsewhere for information -- visual studio and other programs have changed quite a lot over the last 13 years! (Today the modern PC has lots of ram, you can buy an i7 with 32GB, SSD, etc. for next to nothing now).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Visual Studio Update 1 RTM](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/visual-studio-update-1-rtm/) now (2015) has Perl support, along with Go, Java, R, Ruby, and Swift.

Comment: link doesnt work any longer. Could this be the one?
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/visual-studio-update-1-rtm/

Answer (score 14):

### Old Answer (still applies unless you are using Visual Studio Update 1 RTM (2015) or later)

In short. No, there doesn't seem to be a good plugin for it.

If you use Perl rarely, I would recommend sticking with Visual Studio for Microsoft languages and [Padre](http://padre.perlide.org/) for Perl.

However, if you use Perl as much or more than Microsoft languages, you might want to check out [Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/), which has support for [C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8607/any-good-way-to-use-emacs-for-c-development), [VB.NET](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/vbnet-mode.el), and Perl. Emacs is designed to be a "one-stop-shop" for all you do all day long, including browsing the web. You can come into work, start using Emacs and never have to leave it until it is time to go home.

*disclaimer: The answer above is geared toward the Original Poster. I'm a big fan of [vim](http://www.vim.org/about.php). Personally, if I were thrust into a situation where I had to work with C# and Perl on the same project, I would get [ViEMU for Visual Studio](http://www.viemu.com/) and then use two editors: Visual Studio for C# and vim for Perl.*

---

If this is something you are willing to spend some time on, check out [defining your own syntax highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115388/how-can-i-customize-the-syntax-highlighting-in-visual-studio-2005) for Visual Studio.

Comment: Note that five years later, the [answer is now yes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2015/11/30/visual-studio-update-1-rtm.aspx). :)

Answer (score 6):

[Komodo Edit](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit) is quite nice, and free.  code folding and other good stuff.

Answer (score 2):

A work-in-progress Visual Studio [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=scriplit.perl6-lsp) for Perl6 (not the Perl5 asked by the OP) is incrementally more full-featured.  It is released under the [MIT License](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items/scriplit.perl6-lsp/license) and its [repository](https://github.com/scriplit/vscode-languageserver-perl6) is on GitHub.  As a prerequisite, Perl6 (e.g., [Rakudo](https://rakudo.perl6.org/downloads/rakudo)) needs to already be installed.

Comment: Note, this applies only to Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 0):

For Perl syntax highlight `ext install perl6`

Install this extension [To Run Perl and Other languages](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner)

Comment: Caveat. Your link looks to be useful for "visual studio code" and not necessarily for the desktop versions of visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround for Visual Studio desktop version is to use C++ syntax highlighting.

- Go to Options -> Text Editor -> File Extension
- Enter extension "pl" (no dot)
- Assign it to "Microsoft Visual C++"
- Click "Add"

If necessary, repeat the same steps for "cgi" extension.

Comment: This answer can be used as a workaround but I want to add clear instructions

Go to File  -> Preferences -> Settings -> Text Editor -> Files.


In Files options you will find **Associations** where you can add Item and value

For example if we want to treat all .mc files as perl files you will add
Item ->   *.mc  value -> perl

Comment: @HemanthVatti To clarify, your instruction is valid for "Visual Studio Code", my post was about "Visual Studio Desktop". These are very different programs.