# How can I use Perl in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, perl, visual-studio

**SITUATION:** I am a C#.Net developer who is accustomed to Visual Studio 2010 Premium/Ultimate, but my new (long term) employer uses Perl and Java for just about everything.

**QUESTION:** How can I get Perl to work in Visual Studio 2010? I know there is an existing post, [Is there a Perl extension for Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755892/is-there-a-perl-extension-for-visual-studio), on Stack regarding this inquiry, but the post is nearly four years old- A lifetime in the software lifespan. Surely someone has created something to satisfy this need by now?

**NOTE:** I hate.. err .. seriously dislike, Eclipse and Java based applications, so I am really just looking for a go/no-go for getting Perl to Work in Visual Studio. As a bonus, if you also know if it's possible to work with Java in V.S. I welcome the insight.

-- As always, thanks for lending your time and knowledge to the community. --

Comment: I don't have an answer for the question as it's written, but I'd like to offer an alternative approach.  There are IDE's (like VS) for Perl.  My favorite is Komodo.  There's a free Editor-only version, so you can try to see if you like the editor, before paying $300 or so for the full IDE.  I've been a VERY happy user of this IDE for many, many years, and strongly recommend it to anyone doing Perl dev.

Comment: My fault, I should have addressed this in my statement. My company is as such that purchasing, testing and integrating new software is both lengthy and costly. I currently have Visual Studio 2010 Premium and Eclipse at my disposal. Eclipse, and that frustrating Ant builder, are garbage IMO. Granted, they're better than I could build myself, but as a developer/consumer, I choose VS. Or, if no solution is found, MS Notepad.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about perl, but this might do you for Java:
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bc561769-36ff-4a40-9504-e266e8706f93

Comment: try adding some content from the link to your answer as link only answers are not recommended. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask